# Copying file from local machine to AWS EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible, activemq-artemis

I'm using [mqperf](https://github.com/softwaremill/mqperf) repo for benchmarking messaging queue using AWS. I'm trying to tell ansible to instead to download from a link of messaging queue, it should just copy from my machine a builded package for specific MQ.

Example when installing Artemis:

```
- name: Create artemis user
  user:
    name: "{{ artemis_username }}"
    shell: /bin/bash

- name: Download artemis
  get_url:
    dest: "{{ artemis_download_dest }}"
    url:  "{{ artemis_download_url }}"
    
- name: Unpack archive
  unarchive:
    copy:    no
    dest:    /opt
    src:     "{{ artemis_download_dest }}"
    creates: /opt/{{ artemis_name }}
    owner:   "{{ artemis_username }}"

- name: Create user-friendly link
  file:
    state: link
    src: /opt/{{ artemis_name }}
    dest: /opt/artemis
```

I want instead of to download from specific URL , I want to tell it to do that instead from location on my machine.

Is this possible to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the copy module in Ansible, https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/copy_module.html

```
- name: Copy file onto remote machine
  copy:
    src: /srv/myfiles/foo.conf
    dest: /etc/foo.conf
```